# Any better script using regular expressions?

Tags: python

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def reader(filename):

    with open(filename) as f:

        file = f.read()

        regex = r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'

        final = re.findall(regex, file)

        return final

def count(final):

    print(Counter(final))



if __name__ == '__main__':

    file_name = input("Enter file name: ")

    count(reader(file_name))
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory context.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The code review should be from a working project you have written. The title should explain what the code does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are not planning to reuse these functions elsewhere, it does not make a whole lot of sense to split the logic like so. It does not make a lot of sense to use this python script as a CLI tool, either - `grep -o | wc -l` will do it for you, but I digress.

Feeding the filename after you run the script results in some poor usability - I would rather use argparse or, if you plan to do it interactively, not exit after one run. I would instead go with something like

```
import re
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    pattern = r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
    with open(args.filename) as f:
        print(len(re.findall(pattern, f.read())))
```

Comment: I disagree with the function-reuse statement. By its nature, Python allows for reasonable unit testing at the script level when there is a sane function structure. By comparison, your proposal is a huge pain to test.

Comment: Said another way: the whole point of a main guard (which you have preserved) is to allow for outside imports of the functions in this file.

Comment: @Reinderien Oh, yes, sorry. I agree; my point was rather that in how OP has presented their code, I (personally) see little merit in having reader() and count() functions defined like so - if anything, it would be probably better to make something like count_ip_addresses(filename) and combine the functionality of two in there. At least this is my sneaking suspicion. Given the use case is extremely non-obvious here, I would stick to the "you won't need it" principle: refactor when it is clear how the code will be reused and do not overcomplicate things at start.